# What happened to my books in iPad update?

Tags: icloud, books

My books got uploaded to iCloud and then disappeared. Can't find my 1000+ PDFs and epubs anywhere. I turned on an off, syncing, but to no avail. I updated iOS to 13.3, and the Apple Books automatically started uploading all my books to iCloud. The books were more than 15GB, and I had only 4 GB left in iCloud. I had the syncing turned off. But with the update to 13.3 iOS, it turned the syncing on, and now I have no way to find or retrieve my books. Walla! Magic. Great 'Jobs', Apple.

Can someone help me get my books back? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem since iOS 13, but only on my iPad not my iPhone.

I have about 500 books and I like the bookshelf view. After the iOS 13 update, several of the books disappeared. The rectangle for the cover view was still there, but it was blank. When I clicked on it, nothing happened except that the app froze.

The problem seemed to be with books on iCloud, not those stored locally.

I tried various things:

- Switching off syncing for Reading now brought them back - for a short time
- I deleted the app and reinstalled it. The books displayed correctly as the books downloaded from iCloud but when downloading was complete, they disappeared again.

In the end, changing to the list view seems to be a workaround! The icons are still blank, but the details are shown in the list and the books will download if I click on them.